# Open activity on specific tab click

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I created bottom tabs with icon using `TabLayout` and a non-swipe `ViewPager`. What I want is to open an `Activity` on clicking a specific tab (here `position == 2`). The other tabs will open `Fragment` as it is.

Is there any way to do that?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabs;
    private NonSwipeViewPager viewpager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tabs = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewpager = (NonSwipeViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewpager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this));
        viewpager.setPagingEnabled(false);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        final int PAGE_COUNT = 5;
        private Context context;

        public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return PAGE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new HomeFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new CategoryFragment();
                case 2:
                    return new AddProdFragment();
                case 3:
                    return new MyProdFragment();
                case 4:
                    return new MyProfileFragment();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabs.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.home_white);
        tabs.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.category_white);
        tabs.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.upload_white);
        tabs.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.listing_white);
        tabs.getTabAt(4).setIcon(R.drawable.user_white);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            Log.d(debugTag, "onTabChanged: tab number=" + mTabHost.getCurrentTab());

            switch (mTabHost.getCurrentTab()) {
            case 0:
                //do what you want when tab 0 is selected
                break;
            case 1:
                //do what you want when tab 1 is selected
                break;
            case 2:
                //do what you want when tab 2 is selected
                break;

            default:

                break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Use this for tab click listener.

Comment: Similar to MenuItems?

Comment: in mTabHost.getCurrentTab() you get the tab position,then load the fragment according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended opening an `Activity` on a Tab switch. But anyway, you can do something like this.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new HomeFragment();
        case 1:
            return new CategoryFragment();
        case 2:
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AddProdActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return new AddProdFragment();
        case 3:
            return new MyProdFragment();
        case 4:
            return new MyProfileFragment();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: getting error `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference` @Reaz

Comment: @sam you need to pass a valid context when you're creating a new intent. If you're in an `Activity` you need to create the intent like this. - `Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, AddProdActivity.class);`

Comment: And, return the `AddProdFragment` instead of `null`. As you're not handling the null value. Please see the edited answer.